# Psycopg2 parametrized query with sql format function

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I just ran into this issue with Psycopg2:

```
cur.execute("select format('%s, %s, %s', 'one', 'two', 'three') from foo where bar = %s", ('baz',))
```

which produces tuple index out of range exception.

It is obvious that Psycopg placeholders are in conflict with sql format placeholders. Is there a solution for this other than formating strings at the python level? That would be very helpful because I'm not in direct control of that sql. I just take it and execute it with some predetermined parameters...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use double percent symbols:

```
sql = cur.mogrify("select format('%%s, %%s, %%s', 'one', 'two', 'three') from foo where bar = %s", ('baz',))
print(sql)
```

Out:

```
"select format('%s, %s, %s', 'one', 'two', 'three') from foo where bar = 'baz'"
```